# Multidimensional array to single

Tags: php

I have following multi dimensional array, I need to convert to single array.

I tried `array_column()` and `array_shift()` but it doesn't give full data. I know `array_column()` can give multi dimensional array to single but in this specific case, I am not getting the result. I tried following way but not working.

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$result){  
    if ($k == 'month') $result[] = ['month'=> $v];
    if ($k == 'Total_Monthly_Tickets') {
        $result[count($result)-1]['Total_Monthly_Tickets'] = $v;
    }
});
```

**My original array $data**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => January
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => February
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => March
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => April
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => May
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [month] => June
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [month] => July
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [month] => August
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [month] => September
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [month] => October
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [month] => November
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [month] => December
            [Total_Monthly_Tickets] => 0
        )

)
```

**output expected**

```
Array
(
    [0] => December
    [7] => February
    [5] => March
     ----
     --
     ---
)
```

Comment: So what result structure do you actually want?

Comment: You cannot outright flatten this because arrays cannot have duplicate keys. Specify what it is you're trying to achieve with this code as others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple keys with the same name. PHP would fail on duplicate key `[0] => December` and `[0] => November`.

However, you can have the months as keys and the ticket amount as values.

```
<?php
$input = [
    ['month' => 'January', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'February', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 7],
    ['month' => 'March', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 5],
    ['month' => 'April', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'May', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'June', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'July', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'August', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'September', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'October', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'November', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0],
    ['month' => 'December', 'Total_Monthly_Tickets' => 0]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($input as $item) {
    $output[$item['month']] = $item['Total_Monthly_Tickets'];
}
```

The `$output` then results in:

```
array(12) {
  ["January"]=>
  int(0)
  ["February"]=>
  int(7)
  ["March"]=>
  int(5)
  ["April"]=>
  int(0)
  ["May"]=>
  int(0)
  ["June"]=>
  int(0)
  ["July"]=>
  int(0)
  ["August"]=>
  int(0)
  ["September"]=>
  int(0)
  ["October"]=>
  int(0)
  ["November"]=>
  int(0)
  ["December"]=>
  int(0)
}
```